# Carry variable while traversin

Tags: orientdb, graph-traversal

In my OrientDB database I have a document class A which has 4 fields and a relationship:

- id
- parentId
- source
- terminal
- Rel

I need to select the source of the root element of all the elements that have a terminal set. An example would be:

- A1: (Rel: NULL, id: 1, parentId: NULL, source: **test**)
- A2: (Rel: A1, id: 2, parentId: 1)
- A3: (Rel: A2, id: 3, parentId: 2)
- A4: (Rel: A3, id: 4, parentId: 3, terminal: **no1**)
- A5: (Rel: A4, id: 5, parentId: 4)

What I need to get is:
**terminal: *no1*, source: *test***

What I can do right now is get all the sources, but I do not know to which terminals they belong to:

`SELECT source FROM (TRAVERSE A.Rel FROM (SELECT FROM A WHERE terminal IS NOT NULL) WHILE $depth <= 99) WHERE parentId IS NULL`

I tried playing with  `LET` but was not able to make it work the way I wanted to.

**EDIT**

SELECT FROM A

```
orientdb {GratefulDeadConcerts}> select from A

----+-----+----+--------+------+--------+-----
#   |@RID |id  |terminal|source|parentId|Rel
----+-----+----+--------+------+--------+-----
0   |#15:0|1   |null    |test  |null    |null
1   |#15:1|2   |null    |null  |1       |#15:0
2   |#15:2|3   |null    |null  |2       |#15:1
3   |#15:3|4   |no1     |null  |3       |#15:2
4   |#15:4|5   |null    |null  |4       |#15:3
----+-----+----+--------+------+--------+-----
```

First try with LET

```
orientdb {GratefulDeadConcerts}> SELECT source, $terminal FROM ( TRAVERSE A.Rel FROM ( SELECT FROM A WHERE terminal IS NOT NULL LET $parent.$parent.$terminal = terminal ) ) WHERE parentId IS NULL

----+-----+------
#   |@RID |source
----+-----+------
0   |#-2:1|test
----+-----+------
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (sorry without the database it could be hard)

```
SELECT source, $terminal FROM (
  TRAVERSE A.Rel FROM (
    SELECT FROM A WHERE terminal IS NOT NULL LET $parent.$parent.$t = terminal
  ) WHILE parentId IS NOT NULL
) WHERE parentId IS NULL
```

Comment: I have tried your version (slightly adjusted) and you can see the results in my edit. I have also illustrated the table.